# Convergence of a distribution function

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

I have a problem that has me stumped. Frustratingly enough I can't really get the problem started.

It goes as follows: Let $X_{1},X_{2},...$ be independent $C(0,1)$-distributed random variables. Determine the limit distribution of $Y_{n}=\frac{1}{n}\times\max\left \{ X_{1},X_{2},...,X_{n}\left.  \right \} \right.$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

It may be helpful to know that $\arctan(x)+\arctan(\frac{1}{x})=\frac{\pi }{2}$ and that $\arctan(y)=y-\frac{y^{3}}{3}+\frac{y^{5}}{5}-\frac{y^{7}}{7}+...$

The beginning of my solution: I started with calculating the distribution function of X, which might come in handy: $F_{X}(x)=\int_{-\infty }^{x}f_{X}(t)dt=\frac{1}{\pi }\arctan(x)+\frac{1}{2}$.

I'm thinking this is what I want to calculate: $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }F_{Y_{n}}(y)$. If that is correct, how would I proceed from there?

Comment: What is a $C(0,1)$ distributed random variable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limit distribution of $\frac1n\cdot \max(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)$ for $(X_n)$ i.i.d. standard Cauchy](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1595202/limit-distribution-of-frac1n-cdot-maxx-1-x-2-x-n-for-x-n-i-i-d-st)