# Limit with Cauchy density and arctan

Tags: probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Suppose $\{X_i\}$ is an iid sequence of standard Cauchy variables, i.e each has pdf $\dfrac{1}{\pi(1+x^2)}$ for $x\in \Bbb{R}$. Now I have to show that $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\Pr(X_{(n)}\le nx)$$ exists for each $x\in \mathbb{R}$. I also have to show that the limit, let's call it $\Psi(x)$ is a distribution function. Now, the probability becomes $$\Pr(X_{(n)}\le nx)=\left(\dfrac{1}{\pi}\arctan nx+\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^n$$ But how do I show this limit exists? I have mostly made it into an analysis exercise. But, I would love a different proof which uses probabilistic techniques maybe. But anyways someone give me an idea please. Thanks a lot.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/976294/convergence-of-a-distribution-function  This is another one which asks the same question but has been ignored.