# Limit distribution of $\frac1n\cdot \max(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)$ for $(X_n)$ i.i.d. standard Cauchy

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

> Let $X_1, X_2,\ldots $ be independent, Cauchy $C(0,1)-$distributed random variables. Determine the limit distribution of
>   $$Y_n=\frac 1 {n} \cdot \max{(X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n)}$$
>   as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

*Remark.* It may be helpful to know that

1. $\arctan x + \arctan \frac 1 {x} = \frac \pi 2$ and that
2. $\arctan y = y - \frac {y^3} 3 + \frac {y^5} 5 - \frac {y^7} 7 + \dots$

I not sure how to attack this question, nor how I should handle the $\max{(X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n)}$ in order to find the limit distribution. Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Note that $P(x<Y_n) = P(nx < X_1 \text{ and } nx < X_2 \text{ and } nx < X_3 \text{ and } \ldots \text{ and } nx < X_n )$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}F_{Y_n}(y)&=P(Y_n\le y)=P(\max\{X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n\}\le yn)\\&=P(X_1\le ny, X_2\le ny, \dots, X_n\le ny)=^{\text{independent}}\\&=P(X_1\le ny)P(X_2\le ny)\cdots P(X_n\le ny)=^{\text{identically $X\sim C(0,1)$ distributed}}\\&=\left(F_X(yn)\right)^n\end{align} So $$\lim_{n\to \infty}F_{Y_n}(y)=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(F_X(yn)\right)^n=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac12+\frac1{\pi}\arctan{(ny)}\right)^n=e^{-\frac1{yπ}}\mathbf1_{y> 0}$$

---

Since, by the hints that you are given, for $y>0$: $$\left(\frac12+\frac1{\pi}\arctan(ny)\right)^n\overset{1.}=\left(1+\frac{-\arctan{(1/yn)}}{\pi}\right)^n\overset{2.}\sim_{\infty}\left(1+\frac{-1}{\pi yn}\right)^n\to e^{-1/yπ}$$

Comment: Ah, thank you so much! Was just checking a part of your answer on wikipedia but your edit clarified it. Happy new year!

Comment: @litmus Happy new year to you too. This justification of the first part is now ok, but that of the limit is a bit sloppy, sorry about that.

Comment: No worries, but to double check, using *Remark* 2 can I approximate $\arctan(\frac 1 {n \cdot y})$ $\rightarrow$ $\frac 1 {n \cdot y}$, using only the first term and skip the rest of the series, i.e. the remaining $- \frac {y^3} 3 + \frac {y^5} 5 - \frac {y^7} 7 + \dots$?

Comment: Sorry, I meant that: $\arctan(\frac 1 {n \cdot y})$ is approximatley equal to  $\frac 1 {n \cdot y}$.

Comment: @litmus Yes, I think you can write that. This is exactly the point where my justification is sloppy as I said above.