# Convergence of Maximum of Cauchy Random Variables

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, weak-convergence

Suppose $\{P_n\}$ and P are probability measures on the real line with corresponding distribution functions $\{F_n\}$ and $F$, respectively.
$P_n$ converges weakly to P if and only $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} F_n(x) = F(x)$$
at every point x where F is continuous (this can be seen from Portmanteau theorem). How can we use this fact to prove the following.

Let $X_1,X_2,...$ denote i.i.d. Cauchy random variables with parameter $a>0$. More clearly, the density of $X_i$ is 
$$P(X_i \in dx) = \frac{adx}{\pi(a^2+x^2)}, x \in \mathbb{R}$$
Prove that 
$$\frac{1}{n}\max_{1\leq i \leq n}X_i$$ converges in law to $\frac{1}{T}$ where $T$ is an exponential random variable. What is the rate of $T$ as a function of $a$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1595202/321264

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $F_n(x)$ denote the distribution function of $Y_n = \frac{1}{n}\max\limits_iX_i$. Then,

$$ \begin{eqnarray} F_n(x) &=& \mathbb{P}(Y_n \leq x)\\
&=& \mathbb{P}\left(\max\limits_iX_i \leq nx\right)\\
&=& \mathbb{P}\left(X_i \leq nx, \;\; \forall i\right)\\
&=& (\mathbb{P}(X_1 \leq nx))^n\\
&=& \left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{\pi}\arctan\left(\frac{nx}{a}\right)\right)^n \end{eqnarray}$$

Note that $\arctan(x)$ behaves [asymptotically](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1108811/asymptotically-sharp-upper-and-lower-bound-for-for-arctan) like $\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{1}{x}$. Then, you can show that $F_n(x) \xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty} e^{-\frac{a}{\pi x}}$, which is the distribution function of an [inverse exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_distribution#Inverse_exponential_distribution).

Comment: Could you expand a little bit more on how $P(Y_n \leq x) = (P(X_1 \leq nx)^n)$? I don't see the connection.

Comment: I've added a couple more lines. The third equality follows because the maximum of $(X_1,..,X_n)$ is less than $nx$ if and only if all of them are. The fourth equality follows by independence and the identically distributed assumption.