# Finding $\lim\limits_{n→∞}\left(\frac1π\arctan\left(\frac{nx}π\right)+\frac12\right)^n$

Tags: calculus, limits

Well, as the title says, I'm trying to solve the following limit:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan\left(\frac{nx}{\pi}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\right]^n.$$

This arised in the following context: let $(X_i)$ be a sequence of independent Cauchy random variables. Let $M_n=\max_{1\leq i\leq n}X_i$. I want to calculate the distribution to which $\pi M_n/n$ tends to. My approach went as follows:

$$F_{\pi M_n/n}(x) = \mathbb{P}(\pi M_n/n\leq x)=\mathbb{P}(M_n\leq nx/\pi)=(\mathbb{P}(X_1\leq nx/\pi))^n.$$
Which is equals to
$$\left[\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan\left(\frac{nx}{\pi}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\right]^n.$$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1595202/321264

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that for $t\not=0$,
$$\arctan\left(t\right)+\arctan\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)=\text{sign}(t)\cdot \frac{\pi}{2}.$$
(see for example [Proving that $\arctan(x)+\arctan(1/x)=\pm \pi/2$, could this line of reasoning possibly be correct?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1430520/proving-that-arctanx-arctan1-x-pm-pi-2-could-this-line-of-reasoning-p)).

Hence for $x>0$, as $n\to+\infty$,
$$\left[1-\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan\left(\frac{\pi}{nx}\right)\right]^n
=\exp\left(n\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan\left(\frac{\pi}{nx}\right)\right)\right)\to e^{-1/x}.$$
Are you able/interested to evaluate the limit when $x\leq 0$?

Comment: Actually just for $x>0$. Thats awesome. Thank you